# Prove that $|a| < b \iff -b<a<b$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality, proof-writing

I know I have to prove both sides here so:

$\implies$:

Suppose $|a| < b$. Since $|a|$ is a positive number, we know $b$ is a positive number greater than $|a|$:

- If $a$ is positive, $a < b$
- If $a$ is negative, $a < b$

But for $|a| < b$, it has to be that $a > -b$.
$a < b$ and $a > -b$, therefore $–b < a < b$ is true.

$\impliedby$:

Suppose $-b < a < b$.

- If $a$ is positive, then $b$ is a greater positive number, and $-b$ would be less than $a$
- If $a$ is negative, then $b$ can only be a greater positive number for $-b < a$ to hold

So, $b$ is a greater positive integer than $a$. Therefore, it must be that $|a| < b$.

This was what I came up with but it seems convoluted and kind of forced with the cases. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $|a|<b$ then: if $a\geq 0$ then $a=|a|<b$; if $a<0$ then $-a=|a|<b$ implies that $-b<a$.

Can you prove the other part now, using less text and more math?